# Comment attribute won't save in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to save the comment text section of a comment and it won't save for some reason.
I'm checking my server outputs, and the comment attribute is set, but when actually saved, it turns out as NIL.

Originally it has "comment"=>{"comment"=>"hello dude"}, "commit"=>"Sbmit Comment"

But in the saving it saves NIL.

Here's my form for comments

```
<div class="container">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
<%= form_for([@answer, @comment]) do |f| %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :comment %>
        <%= f.text_area :comment, :cols => "50", :rows => "30"%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Submit Comment" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<p> <em>You must be signed in to comment</em> </p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Here's my comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
        @comment = @answer.comments.new(params[:comments])
        @comment.writer = current_user.username
        @comment.save
            redirect_to question_path(@answer)
    end
end
```

And here's my model.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  attr_accessible :anonymous, :comment, :writer, :votes
end
```

Heres my answers model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :question
    attr_accessible :anonymous, :answer, :commenter, :votes, :comments_attributes
end
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've used params[:comment], however, it says I cannot mass assign attributes to answer, even though answer has attr_accessible: :comments_attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line `@comment = @answer.comments.new(params[:comments])` change `:comments` to `:comment`

Comment: if I use :comment, it says can't mass assign attributes to answer, but my answer has attr_accessible: comments_attributes inside it, route has 'comments' in it.

Comment: In your Answer model add: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments`

Comment: This definitely didn't work 5 minutes ago, but now it works! hm, not sure why but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save with params[:comments] in your controller but what is being passed would respond to params[:comment]